# magento2: add product then save error

Tags: magento2

the error code is :
Class Magento\Downloadable\Api\Data\SampleInterfaceFactory does not exist

I add the product, when I submit and save the product. I test it for many days, it still this error, does I configure it wrong?

the Class of the SampleInterface Factory does not exist?
who can give me the code on how to solve this error?